# how to display spelling suggestion in sharepoint search

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, spelling, fastsearch

how can I get spelling suggestion in shaerpoint search ,

I use

> ```
> query.EnableSpellcheck = SpellcheckMode.Suggest;
> ```

then get the value of property

> SpellingSuggestion
>   of the ResultTableCollection

but I'm not getting any spelling correction if I entered incorrect search keyword

any ideas please ???

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late to answer, were you able to find the solution?
The answer of your question depends if you want to get suggestions or you want spelling auto-correction.

When you use the following:

```
query.EnableSpellcheck = SpellcheckMode.Suggest;
```

FAST will try to find the correct terms in your search query if you did a typo in your search or misspelled something. The results of this suggestion will be in an extendedProperty of the dataset you get as result of your query. No need to fill-up a suggestions dictionnary, FAST provides already a quite big dictionnary of suggestions out-of-the-box.

If what you want is an auto-correction, meaning that your search terms will be corrected, and FAST will do a new search with those new terms, you need that:

```
query.EnableSpellcheck = SpellcheckMode.On;
```

Of course, the remaining option if you don't want suggestions nor auto-correction, you specify:

```
query.EnableSpellcheck = SpellcheckMode.Off;
```

Or, you don't specify anything, because Off is the default value.